# group list of ints by continuous sequence

Tags: python

I have a list of integers...

```
[1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10,11,200,201,202]
```

I would like to group them into a list of lists where each sublist contains integers whose sequence has not been broken.  Like this...

```
[[1,5],[8,11],[200,202]]
```

I have a rather clunky work around...

```
lSequenceOfNum = [1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10,11,200,201,202]

lGrouped = []
start = 0
for x in range(0,len(lSequenceOfNum)):
    if x != len(lSequenceOfNum)-1:
        if(lSequenceOfNum[x+1] - lSequenceOfNum[x]) > 1:
            lGrouped.append([lSequenceOfNum[start],lSequenceOfNum[x]])
            start = x+1

    else:
        lGrouped.append([lSequenceOfNum[start],lSequenceOfNum[x]])
print lGrouped
```

It is the best I could do.  Is there a more "pythonic" way to do this?  Thanks..

Comment: Think of it in terms of where the jumps are instead of where the ranges are.  You can store the results in a simple array of ints where each entry is an index corresponding to a jump in the original array.  I think this is simpler...  and on the off-chance this is going to be reusable or library code you can encapsulate all of that in the workings of a class.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate although I can't look for it right now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming the list will always be in ascending order:

```
from itertools import groupby, count

numberlist = [1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10,11,200,201,202]

def as_range(g):
    l = list(g)
    return l[0], l[-1]

print [as_range(g) for _, g in groupby(numberlist, key=lambda n, c=count(): n-next(c))]
```

Answer (score 5):

I realised I had overcomplicated this a little, far easier to just count manually than use a slightly convoluted generator:

```
def ranges(seq):
    start, end = seq[0], seq[0]
    count = start
    for item in seq:
        if not count == item:
            yield start, end
            start, end = item, item
            count = item
        end = item
        count += 1
    yield start, end

print(list(ranges([1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10,11,200,201,202])))
```

Producing:

```
[(1, 5), (8, 11), (200, 202)]
```

This method is pretty fast:

This method (and the old one, they perform almost exactly the same):

```
python -m timeit -s "from test import ranges" "ranges([1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10,11,200,201,202])"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.47 usec per loop
```

[Jeff Mercado's Method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10420670/722121):

```
python -m timeit -s "from test import as_range; from itertools import groupby, count" "[as_range(g) for _, g in groupby([1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10,11,200,201,202], key=lambda n, c=count(): n-next(c))]"
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.1 usec per loop
```

That's over 20x faster - although, naturally, unless speed matters this isn't a real concern.

---

My old solution using generators:

```
import itertools

def resetable_counter(start):
    while True:
        for i in itertools.count(start):
            reset = yield i
            if reset:
                start = reset
                break

def ranges(seq):
    start, end = seq[0], seq[0]
    counter = resetable_counter(start)
    for count, item in zip(counter, seq): #In 2.x: itertools.izip(counter, seq)
        if not count == item:
            yield start, end
            start, end = item, item
            counter.send(item)
        end = item
    yield start, end

print(list(ranges([1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10,11,200,201,202])))
```

Producing:

```
[(1, 5), (8, 11), (200, 202)]
```

Comment: @Abhijit Quite sure, I tested it. Have you found it to fail?

Comment: Well not sure, but the o/p is not what it should be expected. Can you please have a look into this [IDEONE RUN](http://ideone.com/3sCnZ)

Comment: @Abhijit Just checked, this appears to be a Python 2.x vs 3.x issue. Under 3.x it works fine... I'll try and figure out why.

Comment: Of course, `zip()` isn't lazy in 2.x - there you need [`itertools.izip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) - Now [Fixed](http://ideone.com/R4jBK)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this efficiently in three steps

given

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10,11,200,201,202]
```

Calculate the discontinuity

```
     [1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10,11 ,200,201,202]
-      [1,2,3,4,5,8,9 ,10 ,11 ,200,201,202]
----------------------------------------
       [1,1,1,1,3,1,1 ,1  ,189,1  ,1]
(index) 1 2 3 4 5 6 7  8   9   10  11 
                *          *
rng = [i+1 for i,e in enumerate((x-y for x,y in zip(list1[1:],list1))) if e!=1] 
>>> rng
[5, 9]
```

Add the boundaries

```
rng = [0] + rng + [len(list1)]
>>> rng
[0, 5, 9,12]
```

now calculate the actual continuity ranges

```
[(list1[i],list1[j-1]) for i,j in zip(list2,list2[1:])]
[(1, 5), (8, 11), (200, 202)]

LB                [0,   5,    9,  12]
UB             [0, 5,   9,    12]
     -----------------------
indexes (LB,UB-1) (0,4) (5,8) (9,11)
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite old, but I thought I'll share my solution anyway

Assuming `import numpy as np`

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10,11,200,201,202]

np.split(a, array(np.add(np.where(diff(a)>1),1)).tolist()[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

pseudo code (with off-by-one errors to fix):

```
jumps = new array;
for idx from 0 to len(array)
if array[idx] != array[idx+1] then jumps.push(idx);
```

I think this is actually a case where it makes sense to work with the indices (as in C, before java/python/perl/etc. improved upon this) instead of the objects in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that should be easy to read:

```
def close_range(el, it):
    while True:
        el1 = next(it, None)
        if el1 != el + 1:
            return el, el1
        el = el1

def compress_ranges(seq):
    iterator = iter(seq)
    left = next(iterator, None)
    while left is not None:
        right, left1 = close_range(left, iterator)
        yield (left, right)
        left = left1

list(compress_ranges([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 200, 201, 202]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar questions:
[Python - find incremental numbered sequences with a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16315189/python-find-incremental-numbered-sequences-with-a-list-comprehension)
[Pythonic way to convert a list of integers into a string of comma-separated ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429510/pythonic-way-to-convert-a-list-of-integers-into-a-string-of-comma-separated-rang)

```
input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 10, 11, 12, 17]

i, ii, result = iter(input), iter(input[1:]), [[input[0]]]
for x, y in zip(i,ii):
    if y-x != 1:
        result.append([y])
    else:
        result[-1].append(y)

>>> result
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [8], [10, 11, 12], [17]]

>>> print ", ".join("-".join(map(str,(g[0],g[-1])[:len(g)])) for g in result)
1-4, 8, 10-12, 17

>>> [(g[0],g[-1])[:len(g)] for g in result]
[(1, 4), (8,), (10, 12), (17,)]
```