# Python - find incremental numbered sequences with a list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a sequence of numbers in a list and I'm looking for an elegant solution, preferably list comprehension, to get the individual sequences (including single values). I have solved this small problem but it is not very pythonic.

The following list defines an input sequence:

```
input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 10, 11, 12, 17]
```

The desired output should be:

```
output = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [8],
  [10, 11, 12],
  [17],
]
```

Comment: Could there be two identical numbers in a row, i.e, `[1,2,2,3,5]`?

Comment: No, all numbers are unique and n + 1 will always be greater than n.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby, count
>>> nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 10, 11, 12, 17]
>>> [list(g) for k, g in groupby(nums, key=lambda n, c=count(): n - next(c))]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [8], [10, 11, 12], [17]]
```

Comment: Can you see into the future? That's just... amazing.

Comment: @Haidro it's not mine though :P

Comment: It works - but it's not really self-explaining code.

Comment: @jamylak Ah, where from?

Comment: Does it work by making sure the difference between each element is 1? ( in n - next(c) )

Comment: @Haidro I can't find the exact post. It was a recipe from `itertools` I believe.

Comment: @HennyH: No, `c` is a counter, so it gives each element in the list an index (`0`, `1`, etc.) then groups values on the difference between their index and their actual value. `[1, 2, 3, 4]` all differ from their index by `1`, `[8]` differs from it's index by 4, etc.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ahh, that's ingenious!

Comment: I found the other similar question, it's a superset of this one, I posted it as a possible duplicate

Comment: I found [this blog post](http://jonathanchang.org/coding/group-consecutive-number-ranges) showing off this technique. And an earlier reference to it on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5196/grouping-consecutive-numbers-into-ranges-in-python-3-2).

Comment: But Gnibblers reference here is still the earliest I can locate.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Earlier one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154249/identify-groups-of-continuous-numbers-in-a-list Maybe @gnibbler was first to make the `count` edit, which I like more. Also look at the quote in that post: "Python docs have a very neat recipe for this:" There's a link there that no longer works. Ahh they have removed *examples* since 2.6, here's the last one: http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/itertools.html#examples

Comment: @jamylak: The 2.4 Tex documentation has it, see the [mercurial repository version](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.4/Doc/lib/libitertools.tex#l425). Indeed, the 2.6 [rest source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.6/Doc/library/itertools.rst#l596) also lists it still.

Comment: @jamylak: It was present in the docs from python 2.4 until 2.6; [Raymond's commit that removed them](http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/4cddef144428) doesn't give much in the way of reasoning for their removal.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Not sure why they were removed... actually [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/303279-getting-items-in-batches/#c7) might be the first use or close enough

Comment: We should really move this to the [Python chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python). :-) I discounted that reference because it doesn't batch by consecutive numbers, but batches items instead (it is a variant of the grouper recipe).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks but I think I've taken this too far now! I should get back to work :)

Comment: @jamylak: And the [original commit](http://hg.python.org/cpython/diff/897de9208199/Doc/lib/libitertools.tex) for the example credits Guido with the idea, and was made in 2004.

Answer (score 8):

Pythonic means simple, straightforward code, and not one-liners.

```
def runs(seq):
    result = []
    for s in seq:
        if not result or s != result[-1][-1] + 1:
            # Start a new run if we can't continue the previous one.
            result.append([])
        result[-1].append(s)
    return result

print runs([1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 10, 11, 12, 17])
```