# Calculate difference between adjacent items in a python list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of millions of numbers.  I want to find out if the difference between each number in the ordered list is the same for the entire list.

list_example = [ 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, ..etc etc etc]

What's the best way to do this?

My try:

```
import collections

list_example = [ 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40 ]

count = collections.Counter()

for x,y in zip(list_example[0::],list_example[1::]):
    print x,y,y-x
    count[y-x] +=1

if len( count ) == 1:
    print 'Differences all the same'
```

Result:

```
0 5 5
5 10 5
10 15 5
15 20 5
20 25 5
25 30 5
30 35 5
35 40 5
Differences all the same
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428769/finding-the-largest-delta-between-two-integers-in-a-list-in-python

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - Differences between elements of a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400840/python-differences-between-elements-of-a-list)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The straight approach here is the best:

```
x = s[1] - s[0]
for i in range(2, len(s)):
    if s[i] - s[i-1] != x: break
else:
    #do some work here...
```

Comment: I like this answer because it's simple and allows short cutting if a different difference is found.

Answer (score 28):

Using pure Python:

```
>>> x = [0,5,10,15,20]
>>> xdiff = [x[n]-x[n-1] for n in range(1,len(x))]
>>> xdiff
[5, 5, 5, 5]
>>> all([xdiff[0] == xdiff[n] for n in range(1,len(xdiff))])
True
```

It's a little easier, and probably faster, if you use NumPy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> xdiff = np.diff(x)
>>> np.all(xdiff[0] == xdiff)
True
```

But both of these create two extra lists (or arrays, in the case of NumPy) which may gobble up your available memory if you have millions of numbers.

Answer (score 9):

Need notice that the list may have millions of numbers. So ideally, we shouldn't iterate over the entire list unless it's necessary. Also we need avoid construct new list, which may have significant memory consumption. Using all and a generator will solve the problem

```
 >>> x = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
 >>> all(x[i] - x[i-1] == x[i+1] - x[i] for i in xrange(1, len(x) - 1))
 True
```

Comment: A more succinct and better documented solution than my second attempt.. +1

Comment: you compute twice the diff between 2 elements, for i = 2, n-2. maybe you should extract the diff into a variable, and compare against it.

Answer (score 7):

[itertools.izip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) is great for this kind of thing:

```
>>> lst = [1,1,2,3,5,8]
>>> [y-x for x, y in itertools.izip (lst, lst[1:])]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: You can also use `itertools.starmap` to make it more efficient: `itertools.starmap(operator.sub, itertools.izip(lst[1:], lst))`

Answer (score 3):

I came to this while playing around:

```
>>> exm = [0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35]
>>> len(set(exm[a + 1] - exm[a] for a in range(0, len(exm) - 1))) == 1
```

What I do is for each pair of consecutive items determine their difference in a generator.
I then add all those differences to a set to only keep the unique values. If the length of this set is 1 all the differences are the same.

---

Edit: Looking at [cldy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172933/calculate-difference-between-adjacent-items-in-a-python-list/7173025#7173025) you can halt execution early when any item is found not the be the same as your initial difference:

```
>>> exm = [0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35]
>>> initial_diff = exm[1] - exm[0]
>>> difference_found = any((exm[a + 1] - exm[a]) != initial_diff 
                                for a in range(1, len(exm) - 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> x=[10,15,20,25]
>>> diff=(x[-1]-x[0])/(len(x)-1)
>>> diff
5
>>> all(x[i]+diff==x[i+1] for i in range(len(x)-1))
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using the [diff function](http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List#head-37c6c7ffae4e0925823e02735de299a00e413689) in `numpy`.

e.g.

```
import numpy
numpy_array = numpy.zeros(10**6)
for i in xrange(10**6):
    numpy_array[i] = i
print numpy.any(numpy.diff(a) == 1)
```

> True

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using iterators just for comparison.. and possibly an advantage of not needing to know the length of your input data; you might be able to avoid having the millions of list items loaded into memory in the first place...

```
from itertools import tee, izip

# From itertools recipes: http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)

class DifferenceError(Exception):
  pass

def difference_check(data):
  idata = pairwise(data)
  (a,b) = idata.next()
  delta = b - a
  for (a,b) in idata:
    if b - a != delta:
      raise DifferenceError("%s -> %s != %s" % (a,b,delta))
  return True
```

Comment: but for speed up, you should use generator list instead of manual iteration(build in function are faster). all(b-a==delta for a,b in idata)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I used the following method:

```
foo = map(lambda x: lst[x+1]-lst[x],range(len(lst)-1))
```

Comment: Use `\`\`\`python` before and `\`\`\`` after the code (at the beginning of the line) so the keywords, variables will be highlighted.