# Solving max delta within an array

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I'm having issues determining my maximum value calculated in my for loop. I'm using Python to evaluate an array to determine the maximum delta in a sequence i.e. maximum value i+1-i.

I'm having two issues:

1. SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
2. I don't know how to pull the largest calculated iterated value from my for loop

Tried having other variables to compare largest values etc

```
prices=[7,1,5,3,6,4]
profit_loss=0
for i in range(0,len(prices)-1):
        profit_loss=prices[i+1] - prices[i]
        return(profit_loss)
        print(profit_loss)
```

Maximum value should be 4 and the results of my print are below:

```
-6
4
-2
3
-2
```

This question is unique because I am looking to understand why the return function is not necessary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the largest delta between two integers in a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428769/finding-the-largest-delta-between-two-integers-in-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't `return` outside a function. In fact, you don't need `return` here:

```
prices = [7,1,5,3,6,4]
profit_loss = -float('inf')

for i in range(len(prices)-1):
    change = prices[i+1] - prices[i]
    if change > profit_loss:
        profit_loss = change

print(profit_loss)  # 4
```

More idiomatic than positional indexing, use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate elements of `prices` pairwise:

```
for i, j in zip(prices, prices[1:]):
    change = j - i
    if change > profit_loss:
        profit_loss = change
```

More succinctly, use [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) with a generator comprehension:

```
profit_loss = max(j - i for i, j in zip(prices, prices[1:]))  # 4
```

Or use the [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) equivalent:

```
from operator import sub
profit_loss = max(map(sub, prices[1:], prices))  # 4
```

Comment: This is a great explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
prices = [7, 1, 5, 3, 6, 4]
profit_loss = 0
for i in range(0, len(prices)-1):
    res = prices[i+1] - prices[i]
    if res > profit_loss:
        profit_loss = res
print(profit_loss)
```